# Возвращение класса Python

Tags: python

Всем добрый вечер. Скажите, в каких случая нужно возвращать сам класс? Например для метода __ lshift __ нужно возвращать класс: **P.S. Note - класс**

```
    def __lshift__(self, other):
        return Note(list_with_n[(list_with_n.index(self.a) - other) % N], self.f)
```

**Зачем нам нужно писать return CLASS_NAME?** Когда и зачем нужно возвращать класс?

Comment: **Непонятна суть вопроса** 
_В этот вопрос следует включить больше подробностей и уточнить проблему._

Comment: @ Victor VosMottor, изменил. Зачем нужно возвращать класс, т.е. return class_name... ?

Comment: Всё равно ничего непонятно. В показанном здесь коде возвращается вовсе не класс, а экземпляр класса (объект)

Comment: @andreymal Это не цпп, класс и объект в питоне примерно синонимы ;)

Comment: По-моему это очевидно: выполните 1 << 2, будет 4, что это?: правильно тоже инт. Т.е. что было на входе, то стало на выходе ;)

Comment: это создается временный объект класса `Note` и уже этот временный объект возвращается

Comment: Зачем мы пишем return Note... ??? Зачем это слово NOTE??? ВОТ В ЧЕМ ВОПРОС ЗАКЛЮЧАЕТСЯ. ЗАЧЕМ ПИШЕМ СЛОВО NOTE. NOTE ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ КЛАССОМ. БЫВАЮТ СИТУАЦИИ, КОГДА НУЖНО ПИСАТЬ НАЗВАНИЕ КЛАССА. ТАК ВОТ ВОПРОС КОГДА И ЗАЧЕМ

Comment: @Евгений `Note(параметры)` создает экземпляр класса `Note`, передав `параметры` последовательно в методы `__new__` и `__init__`, сам класс никуда не передается. И незачем так орать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возвращать класс нужно в вызывающую функцию,чтобы она воспользовалась методами этого обьекта,ведь возвращается обьект класса,ну а этот обьект по какой то причине был создан в вызываемой функции,например если вы list создаете внутри функции вы можете передать ссылку на него.

Answer (score 2):

Ну вот вам искусственный пример, в котором возвращается и используется класс:

```
import random

class A:
    def do():
        print('Welcome!')

class B:
    def do():
        print('Привет!')

class C:
    def random_hello():
        if random.randint(0,2) == 0:
            return A
        else:
            return B

c = C.random_hello()
c.do()
```

В переменной `c` получается случайным образом либо класс `A`, либо класс `B`, и мы вызываем функцию этого класса, не зная, какой у нас класс, нам всё-равно, у них у обоих есть эта функция.

В вашем же примере возвращается `экземпляр класса`, это практически тоже самое, что в моём примере, но у вас получается как бы **настроенный** класс. Т.е. класс то вы возвращаете один и тот же, но поведение у него может быть разное в зависимости от инициализации класса. Опять же пример:

```
import random

class A:
    def __init__(self, word):
        self.welcome = word
    def do(self):
        print(self.welcome)

class B:
    def make_hello(word):
        return A(word)

c = B.make_hello('Привет!')
d = B.make_hello('Welcome!')

c.do()
d.do()
```

Вывод:

```
Привет!
Welcome!
```

Comment: Прикольно), а где такому учат?

Answer (score 1):

У вас в примере нет возврата класса: `Note(...)` - это создание нового объекта вашего класса.

Зачем тут создается этот объект:

В результате применения оператора (оператора сдвига в данном случае) обычно получается объект (новый или уже существующий) того же класса, что и изначальный объект: по аналогии, если мы делаем сдвиг влево для целого числа, то результатом будет тоже целое число (объект класса "целое число"). Так и здесь - когда вы применяете оператор к своему объекту, оператор возвращает новый объект этого класса.

В целом, результатом выполнения оператора может быть и объект другого класса (например, при делении целого числа на целое может получиться число с плавающей точкой). Но в данном случае логично возвращать именно объект того же класса.

Answer (score 0):

Например, чтобы использовать декораторы для классов, которые перегружают/изменяют внутренние методы.